# How to move an existing image into storage in laravel 6?

Tags: laravel

I have the image called "student_image.jpeg" being set up as a default image.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('avatar')->default('images/student_image.jpeg');
        });
    }
```

It's initially located in the public folder. I want it to be in the `storage/avatars/admin` folder.

[image]

I don't understand how to move this image into the folder. I've tried to use `Storage::move` when seeding the admin table but it doesn't work and I don't think it's the right place to put the code.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use TCG\Voyager\Models\Role;
use TCG\Voyager\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class AdminSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (User::count() == 0) {
            $role = Role::where('name', 'admin')->firstOrFail();

            User::create([
                'name'           => 'Admin',
                'email'          => 'admin@involta.ru',
                'birthday'       => '1998.09.25 00:00:00',
                'phone'          => '8-999-888-77-22',
                'department_id'  => '3',
                'password'       => bcrypt('admin@involta.ru'),
                'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
                'role_id'        => $role->id,
            ]);

            Storage::move('public/images/student_image.jpeg', 'storage/avatars/admin/student_image.jpeg');

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `Storage` facade to move this image unless you setup a storage disk that points to the `/public` folder, what you could do instead is the following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

File::move(
    public_path('images/student_image.png'),
    Storage::path('avatars/admin/student_image.png')
);
```

This will move the file into `/storage/app/avatars/admin`, but since you are not using the default folder structure provided by Laravel you have tell the `Storage` facade which disk to use in order to get the image into `/storage/avatars/admin`.

Something like this: `Storage::disk('your-disk')->path('avatars/admin/student_image.png')`

I would probably place this code into the migration that updates the avatar columns default value and all existing values that still point to `images/student_image.jpeg`, so it will only be executed once.

Or even better add this image into your vcs, that way you would not have to move it at all, but instead just delete the old one.